# Comparison according part between React.createClass and React.Component

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, I am wondering if anyone could give me a comparison between `createClass` and `extends Component`

**The first question** is why we need React.Component since we already have createClass?

Second, something specific is:

**1. What does this.state looks like in `extends Component` mode: I try to use this.state in constructor(), but failed as `undifined`**, does that mean I have to build `this.state` myself by giving it the whole state tree?

And one question for both modes:

If I want to use setState() with a complex object(which has nested data structure) **how can I only update according part**, for example, say the state is like:

```
State = {
    title: "",
    attrs: {
        size: {
            width:"100px",
            height: "100px"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I only update the height using setState()? Should I use it like

```
setState({
    attrs: {
        size: {
            height:"200px"
        }
    }
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are plenty of answers on this topic up there: [link](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/), [link](https://reactjsnews.com/composing-components)
2. The state should be initialized in constructor, before you do so - its undefined:

   ```
   public constructor(props, context)
   {
       super(props, context)

       this.state = {
           Clients: [],
       };
   }
   ```
3. You can always update just part of the state and then force update:

   ```
   this.state.attrs.size.height = 200;
   this.forceUpdate();
   ```

   Or just update the state object and reassign it using `setState` again.

Comment: thanks, another question related to this is: when I tried the tutorial in facebook site, it seems that most cases still written with createClass(), I wonder which mode is recommended: the createClass or extends Component

Comment: My personal opinion is - extends - as it is the future of javascript.

Comment: Thanks, BTW, what is that `context` means in constructor?

Answer (score 1):

React.createClass was the older way to define a react component. `class` did not really exist within javascript at the time so this was React's implementation of 'classes';

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class ReactComponent extends Component
```

is the newer way to do define a react component based on es2015 classes.

State should  behave the same way no matter how you define the component.

Within the constructor you should be able to define `this.state`.

I would look into the Flux architecture and implement either Redux or AltJS to help with the data flow architecture.

In your state if you have an object :

```
q = {
  title: "Test",
  body : "Test123"
}
```

and want to update the title ... you have to do the following :

```
var x = this.state.q;
x.title = "New Title";
this.setState({ q: x });
```

You can not modify an object attribute in state. You have to update the attribute and setState with the entire new object.

Comment: thanks, another question related to this is: when I tried the tutorial in facebook site, it seems that most cases still written with createClass(), I wonder which mode is recommended: the createClass or extends Component

Comment: @Kuan I would assume the facebook site still uses createClass because that doesn't rely on es2015. Not all browsers support es2015 yet so you have to use a transpiler like babel. Most "newer" examples use `extends Component` that I've seen. And it also depends on if you are wanting to use es2015 functionality in your JS code